# Auth::attempt() only returns true on database line 1

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have a weird problem with my `Laravel-4 Authentication`. Only my first database line can login in my Laravel project, the others return false.

I use Authentication a bit different than expected. I don't have a username, only a password, which is also called 'code'. I also tried this with a username (as "party"), but that also doesn't seem to work.

I added a table "password_unh" (= password unhashed) to my database, of course this is not how it's supposed to be in the end, but it's to check my password (since my password table is hashed), and I also see this as my 'party'.

Here is my code (I put the code about 'party' in comment)

login.blade.php

```
@extends("layout")
@section("content")
    {{ Form::open([
        "route"        => "party/login",
        "autocomplete" => "off"
    ]) }}
        <!--{{ Form::label("party", "Party") }}
        {{ Form::text("party", Input::get("party"), [
            "placeholder" => "Christmas party Smith"
        ]) }}-->
        {{ Form::label("code", "Code") }}
        {{ Form::password("code") }}

        @if($errors->has())
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <div class='error'>{{ $error }}</div>
            @endforeach
        @endif
        {{ Form::submit("login") }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
@stop
@section("footer")
    @parent
    <script src="//polyfill.io"></script>
@stop
```

UserController.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction() {

        $errors = new MessageBag();
        if ($old = Input::old("errors"))
        {
            $errors = $old;
        }
        $data = [
            "errors" => $errors
        ];
        if (Input::server("REQUEST_METHOD") == "POST")
        {
            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
                //"party" => "required",
                "code" => "required"
            ]);

            if ($validator->passes())
            {
                $credentials = [
                    //"password_unh" => Input::get("party"),
                    "password" => Input::get("code")
                ];
                if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
                {
                    return Redirect::to('profile');
                }
            }
            $data["errors"] = new MessageBag([
                "code" => [
                    "Party and/or code invalid."
                ]
            ]);
            //$data["party"] = Input::get("party");

            return Redirect::route("party/login")
                ->withInput($data);
        }
        return View::make("party/login", $data);
    }
}
```

database users table
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy, you should have at least `username` and `password` field in `$credentials` array.
I can see you miss that in database table as well.

Comment: To note, you can add another fields into `$credetials` (they have to match column names in `users` table). For example if you set `$credentials['active'] = true;`, Laravel with only look for users that have set `active = 1` in database table...

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal but you could do

```
$user = User::where('password',Hash::make(Input::get('code')));

if(Auth::loginUsingId($user->id))
{
   //do  blah
}
```

or

```
if(Auth::login($user))
{
   //do  blah
}
```